# Error installing arcgis via pip or pipenv

Tags: arcgis

I am trying to install arcgis via the command line, using commands such as:

- py -m pipenv install arcgis
- py -m pip install arcgis
- conda install -c esri arcgis

And regardless of which approach I take, it keeps giving me this error:

Installing...
[=   ] Installing arcgis...[31m[1mError: [0m An error occurred while installing [32marcgis[0m!
Error text: Collecting arcgis
Downloading arcgis-2.0.0.tar.gz (3.7 MB)
---------------------------------------- 3.7/3.7 MB 2.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'

[36m  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [7 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "", line 34, in 
File "C:\Users\heath\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-udrotsx3\arcgis_ddd68d8abb1c44d1a097b8b962e45b1b\setup.py",
line 193, in 
_get_rel_site_packages_dir() + "arcgis/gis/_impl"
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
[0m
This is likely caused by a bug in [32marcgis[0m. Report this to its maintainers.

As mentioned, I have tried installing via pip, pipenv, and conda, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, but I just ran into this error with Python `v3.12` installed in the virtual environment, so for any others, just downgrading the Python version to `3.9`, `3.10`, or `3.11` in the Conda environment solved the issue for me, which [appear to be the latest Python versions](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-python-api/issues/1595) the `arcgis-py` API supports in [their latest release in Oct. 2023](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-python-api/releases/tag/v2.2.0).

This same issue mentioned in the original question was also [raised in their repository](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-python-api/issues/1611) here with Python `v3.7.9`. Note that when trying to install `arcgis` through `conda install -c esri arcgis` with Python `v3.12.2`, I got a `Could not solve for environment specs` error. When trying to use `pip install`, the posted error came up.

```
conda install python 3.11 -n name_of_your_env
conda install -c esri arcgis -n name_of_your_env
```

After downgrading, installing with `pip` or `conda` worked fine.